# What's the short way to add same symbol at the specified place in ncurses?

Tags: python, ncurses

I want to add str `"#"` in `ncurse` screen,with coordinate `x(5 to 24)`,  `y(23 to 42)`
which is a square. But I can't figure out a simple way to do it.

I've tried:

```
stdscr.addstr(range(23,42),range(5,24),'#')
```

But this can't work. It needs 'integer'.

Does anyone can figure out an easy way to do this Job?

Thanks.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan, thanks, how to make those part highlight? And I'm wondering the 'job' need to be capitalized?

Comment: Do you know attributes like A_BLINK, A_BOLD ? check below I added colors and bold...

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Ah, you've added background color, that's what I've missed, thank you!

Comment: in `init_pair()` third argument is for bg color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First two arguments of `addstr` should be row, col as integer but your are passing list:

To make square to like this:

```
for x in range(23,42): # horizontal c 
  for y in range(5,24): # verticale r
    stdscr.addstr(y, x, '#')
```

To fill colors, blinking, bold etc you can use attribute filed in function:

```
from curses import *
def main(stdscr):
    start_color()
    stdscr.clear()  # clear above line. 
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Fig: SQUARE", A_UNDERLINE|A_BOLD)    
    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_WHITE)
    init_pair(2, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_WHITE)
    pair = 1
    for x in range(3, 3 + 5): # horizontal c 
      for y in range(4, 4 + 5): # verticale r
        pair = 1 if pair == 2 else 2
        stdscr.addstr(y, x, '#', color_pair(pair))
    stdscr.addstr(11, 0, 'Press Key to exit: ')
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()    
wrapper(main)
```

Output:

> [image: output]

**Old-answer:**

Do like this for diagonal:

```
for c, r in zip(range(23,42), range(5,24)) :
  stdscr.addstr(c, r, '#')
```

Code example to fill diagonal:

code **x.py**

```
from curses import wrapper
def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()  # clear above line. 
    for r, c in zip(range(5,10),range(10, 20)) :
      stdscr.addstr(r, c, '#')  
    stdscr.addstr(11, 0, 'Press Key to exit: ')
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()

wrapper(main)
```

run: `python x.py`, then you can see:

> [image: output]

To make a Square do like:

```
from curses import wrapper
def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()  # clear above line. 
    for r in range(5,10):
      for c in range(10, 20):
        stdscr.addstr(r, c, '#')        
    stdscr.addstr(11, 0, 'Press Key to exit: ')
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()

wrapper(main)
```

Output:

> [image: square]

PS: from your code it looks like you wants to fill diagonal, so I edited answer later for square.

Comment: Great, the first one works. I've tried ' for x in range(23,42) and y in range(5,24): stdscr.addch(y,x,'#') ' but failed. Guess yours is the right way machine can understand.

Comment: @Mario I didn't read much about it, but may be some coordinate problem. Try by changing values.