# How to clear string in a specific coordinate range in ncurses?

Tags: python, ncurses

So far I've learnt how to use  window.move(y, x) and window.clrtoeol() to clear content at a specific line or from any start point to the end of that line.

I'm designing a game similar to tetris, but the 'block' falls down will cause a collision, then the certain area will be cleared, depend on the block length. So I need to know how to remove strings in a specific coordinate range. For example:

```
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()

for y in range(9,20):
    for x in range(9,20):
        stdscr.addstr(y,x,'#')

stdscr.refresh()
```

the above code make a square with string '#'.
**How could I clear the content start from (10,10) and end at(10,20)?**

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are asking. Can you be more specific? Can you put some examples of what you have tried?

Comment: @rae1, question updated.

Comment: @Mario According to your code you have no string either on `(10, 10)` and on `(10, 20)`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan， sorry, I forget the beginning doesn't count.

Comment: @Mario  No end doesn't counts, btw if you checked [my this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21681563/1673391) to you I have already shown you that you can overwrite on a co-ordinate position.

Comment: you mean by add " " characters?

Comment: @Mario what every you wants.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, OK, I'm going to study it througly.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I found it. window.del(ch), but yet I don't know how to type in a word in ncurses screen. And I want use this input to do some if statement issue. Like, input = 'cool', if input == "cool": stdscr.addstr(1,1,'very cool')

Comment: Do you have any idea about problem above?

Comment: `yet I don't know how to type in a word in ncurses screen` ? Do you wants to make some submit form in ncurses?

Comment: I've ask a question again in ncurses topic. Maybe you can answer it there. I've really did lot of research. @GrijeshChauhan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.delch([y, x])` function can do what you want.

PS:  I'm the questioner, and I found the answer myself.

Comment: If it answers your question you can also accept it.